# Numpy.savetxt() function

Tags: python, numpy

I have a table with several columns and want save it with

```
numpy.savetxt('test.txt', test, fmt='%f')
```

I want save only the last column in float format, all other columns should be integers... For example

```
1 1 1 0.5
1 2 2 0.3
. . .  .
```

How I can enlarge my savetxt function or use some alternative? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fmt can be an array like so:

```
numpy.savetxt('test.txt', test, fmt=['%d', '%d', '%d', '%f'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number of columns is very large you can also do something like this:

```
numpy.savetxt('test.txt', test, fmt= '%d'*15 + '%f')
```

With this code, the first 15 columns are integers whereas the final column is a float.